# how can i change my esp8266 as access point

Tags: android, esp8266

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define DEBUG true
SoftwareSerial esp8266(8,9);                           
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp8266.begin(9600); 
  pinMode(11,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(11,LOW);

  pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(12,LOW);

  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);

  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(10,LOW);

  sendCommand("AT+RST\r\n",2000,DEBUG); // reset module
  sendCommand("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // configure as access point
  sendCommand("AT+CWJAP=\"SSID\",\"PASSWD\"\r\n",3000,DEBUG);
  delay(10000);
  sendCommand("AT+CIFSR\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // get ip address
  sendCommand("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // configure for multiple connections
  sendCommand("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // turn on server on port 80

  Serial.println("Server Ready");
}

void loop()
{

  if(esp8266.available()) // check if the esp is sending a message 
  {
    if(esp8266.find("+IPD,"))
    {
     delay(1000); 
     int connectionId = esp8266.read()-48; // subtract 48 because the read() function returns 
                                           // the ASCII decimal value and 0 (the first decimal number) starts at 48
     esp8266.find("pin=");
     int pinNumber = (esp8266.read()-48); // get first number i.e. if the pin 13 then the 1st number is 1
     int secondNumber = (esp8266.read()-48);
     if(secondNumber>=0 && secondNumber<=9)
     {
      pinNumber*=10;
      pinNumber +=secondNumber; // get second number, i.e. if the pin number is 13 then the 2nd number is 3, then add to the first number
     }

  if((pinNumber==12)&&(pinNumber!=11))
     {digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
     digitalWrite(11,LOW);}
    if((pinNumber==11)&&(pinNumber!=12))
     {digitalWrite(12, LOW);
     digitalWrite(11,HIGH);}    
     // build string that is send back to device that is requesting pin toggle
     String content;
     content = "Pin ";
     content += pinNumber;
     content += " is ";

     if(digitalRead(pinNumber))
     {
       content += "ON";
     }
     else
     {
       content += "OFF";
     }

     sendHTTPResponse(connectionId,content);

     // make close command
  //   String closeCommand = "AT+CIPCLOSE="; 
  //   closeCommand+=connectionId; // append connection id
  //   closeCommand+="\r\n";

  //   sendCommand(closeCommand,1000,DEBUG); // close connection
    }
  }
}

/*
* Name: sendData
* Description: Function used to send data to ESP8266.
* Params: command - the data/command to send; timeout - the time to wait for a response; debug - print to Serial window?(true = yes, false = no)
* Returns: The response from the esp8266 (if there is a reponse)
*/
String sendData(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug)
{
    String response = "";

    int dataSize = command.length();
    char data[dataSize];
    command.toCharArray(data,dataSize);

    esp8266.write(data,dataSize); // send the read character to the esp8266
    if(debug)
    {
      Serial.println("\r\n====== HTTP Response From Arduino ======");
      Serial.write(data,dataSize);
      Serial.println("\r\n========================================");
    }

    long int time = millis();

    while( (time+timeout) > millis())
    {
      while(esp8266.available())
      {

        // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window 
        char c = esp8266.read(); // read the next character.
        response+=c;
      }  
    }

    if(debug)
    {
      Serial.print(response);
    }

    return response;
}

/*
* Name: sendHTTPResponse
* Description: Function that sends HTTP 200, HTML UTF-8 response
*/
void sendHTTPResponse(int connectionId, String content)
{

     // build HTTP response
     String httpResponse;
     String httpHeader;
     // HTTP Header
     httpHeader = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"; 
     httpHeader += "Content-Length: ";
     httpHeader += content.length();
     httpHeader += "\r\n";
     httpHeader +="Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
     httpResponse = httpHeader + content + " "; // There is a bug in this code: the last character of "content" is not sent, I cheated by adding this extra space
     sendCIPData(connectionId,httpResponse);
}

/*
* Name: sendCIPDATA
* Description: sends a CIPSEND=<connectionId>,<data> command
*
*/
void sendCIPData(int connectionId, String data)
{
   String cipSend = "AT+CIPSEND=";
   cipSend += connectionId;
   cipSend += ",";
   cipSend +=data.length();
   cipSend +="\r\n";
   sendCommand(cipSend,1000,DEBUG);
   sendData(data,1000,DEBUG);
}

/*
* Name: sendCommand
* Description: Function used to send data to ESP8266.
* Params: command - the data/command to send; timeout - the time to wait for a response; debug - print to Serial window?(true = yes, false = no)
* Returns: The response from the esp8266 (if there is a reponse)
*/
String sendCommand(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug)
{
    String response = "";

    esp8266.print(command); // send the read character to the esp8266

    long int time = millis();

    while( (time+timeout) > millis())
    {
      while(esp8266.available())
      {

        // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window 
        char c = esp8266.read(); // read the next character.
        response+=c;
      }  
    }

    if(debug)
    {
      Serial.print(response);
    }

    return response;
}
```

hi i have this code the esp will connect to the internet so that i can turn on or turn off led  from a mobile appl i want to change it . i want the esp8266 01 ti be an access point .. i don't want to use the internet  i want the phone to connect directly to the esp8266
what changes do i have to do and how can i configure esp8266 as access point

Answer (score 0):

When you initialized the ESP, you configured it in Station Mode

```
sendCommand("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n",1000,DEBUG); 
sendCommand("AT+CWJAP=\"SSID\",\"PASSWD\"\r\n",3000,DEBUG);
```

In order to configure in AP mode you should replace this with :

```
sendCommand("AT+CWMODE=2\r\n",1000,DEBUG);
```

See [CWMODE documentation](https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_AT/wiki/CWMODE)

> mode：
>   1 means Station mode
>   2 means AP mode
>   3 means AP + Station mode

Comment: what else do I have to change

Comment: That should be enough to be able to access to the ESP through its default IP `192.168.4.1`

Comment: yes it did thanks but one more question if you don't  mind  if I wanted  to use them  both I ll have to change mode to 3 and what else   should I do